# DynamicsCRM QueryExpression Criteria inside an EntityReference

Tags: powershell, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm Using the CRM SDK from PowerShell, Trying to query a contract linked to specific Account name, If I do the query against Account GUID I get the results, but I want to query against the name inside the EntityReference object, and not the GUID, for example (this works fine):

```
$query = new-object Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query.QueryExpression('new_contract')
$query.Criteria.AddCondition('new_account', [Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query.ConditionOperator]::Equal, $AccountGuid)
```

The Above results looks like that:

```
Key                 Value
---                 -----
createdby           Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityReference
createdon           21/10/2014
modifiedby          Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityReference
modifiedon          28/02/2016
modifiedonbehalfby  Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityReference
new_account         Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityReference
[...]               [...]
```

The `new_account` Properties are:

```
Id            : dab2909d-6149-e411-93fc-005056af5481
LogicalName   : account
Name          : CustomerNameText
KeyAttributes : {}
RowVersion    : 
ExtensionData : System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject
```

I want to create a Query for `new_contract` with `new_account` Name LIKE `CustomerNameText`

I tried:

```
  $query.Criteria.AddCondition('new_account',([Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityReference].Attributes['new_account']).Name, [Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query.ConditionOperator]::Like, $AccountName)
```

But it not works get the following error:

```
Exception calling "RetrieveMultiple" with "1" argument(s): "Link entity with name or alias new_account is not found"
At line:2 char:5
+     $temp = $service.RetrieveMultiple($query);
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FaultException`1
```

I hope i'm clear, but if not, comment with any question.

Powershell code is preferable, c# is ok as well

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `QueryExpression` criteria for `EntityReference` name. With `EntityReference` you can only use `Guid`.

If you want to Query by name, you can use `LinkEntity` in QueryExpression. You will have to use `LinkCriteria`

```
var q = new QueryExpression();
            q.EntityName = "new_contract";
            q.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet();
            q.ColumnSet.Columns.Add("new_contractid");

            q.LinkEntities.Add(new LinkEntity("new_contract", "account", "new_account", "accountid", JoinOperator.Inner));
            q.LinkEntities[0].Columns.AddColumns("accountid", "name");
            q.LinkEntities[0].EntityAlias = "temp";
            q.LinkEntities[0].LinkCriteria.AddCondition("name", ConditionOperator.Equal, "yourAccountName");
```

**P.S**If the above snippet, is not working for you. And you want to retrieve by `accountName`. On way to do this is use your existing code using `Guid` of account. But first you have to retrieve `accountGuid by name`. In that case

```
  public Guid getAccountGuidByName(string name)
    {

        QueryExpression accountQuery = new QueryExpression("account");
        accountQuery.Criteria.AddCondition("name", ConditionOperator.Equal, "yourAccountName");
        EntityCollection entCol = Service.RetrieveMultiple(accountQuery);
        if (entCol.Entities.Count > 0)
        {
            return entCol.Entities[0].Id;
        }
       return Guid.Empty;

    }
```

**just for example i don't know how can you call function etc in powershell but i am providing c# code, as you said its ok if it in C#** then use it like below :

```
$query = new-object Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query.QueryExpression('new_contract')
$query.Criteria.AddCondition('new_account', [Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query.ConditionOperator]::Equal, getAccountGuidByName("yourAccountName"));
```

Comment: Thanks, can you please update your answer to match my criteria, e.g. new_contract-->new_account by name, so it will be easier for me to understand your answer and translate it back to powershell

Comment: @Avshalom yes i can but you have to provide me  fields details that are used for relationship. also i think "new_contract" and "new_account" are your custom fields.

Add relationship details to your question

Comment: the `new_contract` is the contracts entity, the `new_account` is custom name for the `account` entity, it has a relationship (but i'm not sure about the name) the `name` field i'm looking for is the name of the `account` entity, I want to find contracts which the account name is "somename"

Comment: @if you have any doubt about relationships you can go to customization's and view all `1:N`, `N:1`,  `N:N`  relationships for any entity.